# MySQL get MAX date

Tags: mysql

I have an Events table and related EventAddress table. I want to get the address of the event that has the latest time on a particular day and less than a given time. So if there are 2 events today, one at 2pm-3pm and one at 5pm-6pm and my next event is at 7pm-8pm, I want to get events with end time earlier than the new event start time. So in the instance, I would want the address of the event that is 5-6pm. Hope that makes sense. The following is what I have so far after trying to follow [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17882188/112680).

```
SELECT
  ea1.Address,
  ea1.City,
  ea1.State,
  ea1.Zip,
  e.EventEndDate
FROM EventAddress ea1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
      Events.EventAddressId,
      MAX(Events.EventEndDate) AS maxdate
    FROM Events
    GROUP BY Events.EventAddressId) max_record
    ON max_record.EventAddressId = ea1.EventAddressId
  INNER JOIN Events e
    ON ea1.EventAddressId = e.EventAddressId
WHERE DATE(e.EventStartDate) = '2014-11-06'
AND e.FranchiseId = 1
AND TIME(e.EventEndDate) <= '18:00:00'
```

EDIT: the inner SELECT returns the correct result, but the end result is still returning 2 events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `MAX(TIME(e.EventEndDate)) AS themax` to the outer select

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

```
WHERE DATE(e.EventStartDate) = '2014-11-06'
AND e.FranchiseId = 1
AND TIME(e.EventEndDate) <= '18:00:00'
```

To either EventStartDate or EventEndDate. I'm not sure how you're data is structured, but I'm assuming it's something like '2014-11-06 18:00:00'.  If so you will need to use the mysql equivalent of datepart.

Comment: `DATE()` and `TIME()` are the datepart equivalents. I can change EventStartDate to EventEndDate but will not have an affect since they are both the same date.

Comment: That makes sense.  Have you tried MAX(TIME(e.EventEndDate)).

Comment: No, but that gave me an idea. I added `MAX(TIME(e.EventEndDate)) AS themax` to the outer select and it appears to be working .

Comment: Great, glad to be of help