# MySQL Select from other Table

Tags: mysql

Its a bit difficult to explain what I actually mean.

I have a statement that looks like

```
select 
    c.categories_name, 
    max(pc.categories_id), 
    pc.products_id 
from 
    products_to_categories pc, 
    categories_description c 
where 
    pc.products_id = 517 
group by 
    pc.products_id
```

In my  `products_to_categories` table is some data stored like

```
|categories_id  |  products_id|
|1              |  515        |
|22             |  515        |
|1              |  517        |
|13             |  517        |
|2              |  520        |
|29             |  520        |
```

Actually I want to select all categories where the product has an category 1.

In this case this would be product 515 and 517.

With my select, it returns me the correct values `22, 13`

because the `group by`brings it to one line each product and the `max()` selects the higher value. Whats exactly what I want.

Now there is a second table where the names of these categories are stored in. I tried several selects without success. And I don't want to use a second select (subselect) to get these names.

Is this even possible ? or do i really have to do a subselect ?

I remember from SQLBase (Older database) that I could use kind of the selected values to compare some in the where clause.... But truly I don't remember how that worked.

I tried

```
select 
    c.categories_name, 
    max(pc.categories_id), 
    pc.products_id 
from 
    products_to_categories pc, 
    categories_description c 
where 
    pc.products_id = 517
    and c.categories_id = pc.categories_id  --i hoped this line helps...
group by 
    pc.products_id
```

Selecting like this returns me the name from the lower ID

To clarify my achievement:

I first want all Products from Table one that has category 1 and an other one. e.g. 13.

After this I only want the higher category (13 in my sample). And finally I want the category name from an other table that has the id 13.

Comment: What's the error message or the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: there is no error... it simply doesnt select what I want. Because in my select I use max and this gives me the right value back but i need also a max in my where to get the correct name. otherwise it selects the name of the first mached id and thats 1 in my case.. and not 13 or 22

Comment: Have you tried using a `JOIN`? A join is meant for selecting data from multiple tables and joining them together.

Comment: There's a lot of confusion in your question. First you say `Actually I want to select all categories where the product has category 1.` Then you say `it returns me the correct values 22, 13`. Then you use max on `category_id` (why if you filter for category_id?) and on the first query you filter for `product_id`.

Try to explain better the issue/what you want to achieve

Comment: @Jelle i you take a look at my select, i am joining allready

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882073/mysql-select-max-date-inside-a-join-statement does not match my question. As I sayed, I dont want to use subselects! and the expected result is diffrent. How ever, jdehesa got me right and solved it.

Comment: I seriously doubt that the accepted answer is correct. If you must avoid a subquery (I've no idea why) you can use the LEFT JOIN... WHERE IS NULL solution provided in the manual - popularly (if inaccurately) known as a strawberry query.

Comment: @Strawberry I dont MUST avoid it, i WANT to avoid it. Just to have a shorter code. It feels kind of better :) And in my case this answere helped me and actually gave me the expacted result. At least for the asked question. In the end the original source is a bit more complicated. So to keep it low, i shortened the question and the answer satisfied me with the expacted result. May there are better solutions but since my question was marked as duplicate (whats truly not!) i propably never know ^^ but I guess thats not necessary.

Comment: "feels better" give me a break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a `having` clause, something like:

```
select 
    c.categories_name, 
    max(pc.categories_id), 
    pc.products_id 
from 
    products_to_categories pc, 
    categories_description c 
where 
    pc.products_id = 517
group by
    pc.products_id, c.categories_name, c.categories_id
having
    max(pc.categories_id) = c.categories_id
```

Comment: unknown column `c.categories_id` in having clause. But autocomplete of my tool says it exists...

Comment: @Dwza Right, I think it's fixed now.

Comment: yes, this is it :D

Comment: why ever some devots the correct answer. Is not understandable for me!

Answer (score -1):

```
 select 
c.categories_name, 
max(pc.categories_id), 
pc.products_id 
from 
     products_to_categories pc 
join categories_description c  on c.categories_id = pc.categories_id
where 
   pc.products_id = 517
group by 
  pc.products_id,c.categories_name
```

U can use inner join that will help

Comment: in the end, yes  looks good but i dont want both results. I just want the max id name and you select brings ob both. min and max. Grouping it right goes back to my old issue.

Comment: it my bad!i didn't understood question ... I will go with above solution then