# sql - multiple primary keys on inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, max, inner-join

I need to count all rows with distinctive ItemID:s with the highest RevisionID on the item with that ItemID. Here's my code (relevant parts):

```
(
SELECT count(parent.ItemID) FROM item AS parent
INNER JOIN item AS child ON parent.ItemID = child.ItemID AND parent.RevisionID = Max(child.RevisionID)
WHERE parent.orderID = orders.orderID AND parent.StatusInfo != '2' 
) as notordered,
```

The code works if you take out "AND parent.RevisionID = Max(child.RevisionID)", but then it takes all the revision of the items. I am aware that I can't use "Max" with INNER JOIN ON, but I couldn't find a way to get it in a way that it was consistent with the rule parent.ItemID = child.ItemID with a subquery. 
Please help.

Example:
Input
A- ID:1 RevID:2
B- ID:1 RevID:3
C- ID:2 RevID:4
Return:
B & C, because they have unique ID:s and the highest RevID with that ID

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Just a hint would be okay, I can work it from there

Comment: give us an example of how is the data is , and how you want the result

Comment: Hint provided. See above. Or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882073/mysql-select-max-date-inside-a-join-statement/17882188#17882188

Comment: Thanks Strawberry! Link answered my question perfectly, and now I'm sorry for doubting the user base! You rule!

Comment: Note that if you don't '@' address the comment to the commentator, they probably won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer hinted by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882073/mysql-select-max-date-inside-a-join-statement/17882188#17882188 was:

```
SELECT count(parent.ItemID) FROM item AS parent
JOIN (SELECT itemID, MAX(RevisionID) as MaxRevision FROM Item GROUP BY ItemID) as child ON parent.ItemID = child.ItemID AND parent.RevisionID = child.MaxRevision
WHERE parent.orderID = orders.orderID 
) as notordered,
```