# No records as result, but the records are available in the DB

Tags: php, sql

**This is my entire function()**

```
public function general_due_donors_list()
{
    $f_diff=date('m')-4; // female date counter 2 for emergency months after last donation
    $m_diff=date('m')-3; // male date counter 2 for emergency months after last donation

    // female for emergency
    $stmt = ("SELECT donorid,fname,mname,gender,dob,zone,city,phoneno,bloodtype FROM donor_info where donorid=(SELECT donorid FROM donor_record group by donorid Having (DATE_FORMAT(MAX(donationdate), '%m')<".$f_diff." or DATE_FORMAT(MAX(donationdate), '%Y')< ".date('Y').") and gender='f')");

    foreach($this->conn->query($stmt) as $li)
    {                
        $info[]=$li;
    }

    // male for emergency
    $stmt = ("SELECT donorid,fname,mname,gender,dob,zone,city,phoneno,bloodtype FROM donor_info where donorid=(SELECT distinct donorid FROM donor_record group by donorid Having (DATE_FORMAT(MAX(donationdate), '%m')<".$m_diff." or DATE_FORMAT(MAX(donationdate), '%Y')< ".date('Y').") and gender='m')");**

    foreach($this->conn->query($stmt) as $li)
    {                 
        $info[]=$li;
    }

    if (!isset($infof))
    {
        $infof=false;
    }
    if(!isset($infom))
    {
        $infom=false;
    }

    $info = array("female" => $infof, "male" => $infom);
    return $info;
}
```

After running this code,I am getting:

> Invalid argument supplied to the foreach loops

Comment: I think its error not related to sql, its through error because of problem in php code , recheck your php parameter(argument ) which one you try to pass query

Comment: show us your table and records

Comment: Hello, please post all your code so we can figure out what's the problem

Comment: guys thanks for the help and this is the entire function

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this query - you can try it in phpMyAdmin and see that it returns a bunch of records.

Comment: What framework are you using? It looks like `$this->conn->query()` doesn't return an iterable value.  Have you var_dumped the return value to see what you are working with?

Comment: @IVOGELOV I discovered that there is something potentially wrong with the posted query; please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you don't need to pass in php variables, and I prefer [an INNER JOINed subquery to find the MAX() donationdate for each respective donor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17882188/2943403).

[db-fiddle.com demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o86gp242BRFgixRFTPm1fL/0)

```
$sql = "SELECT info.donorid, fname, mname, gender, dob, zone, city, phoneno, bloodtype
        FROM donor_info AS info
        JOIN (
            SELECT donorid, MAX(donationdate) donationdate
            FROM donor_record
            GROUP BY donorid
        ) AS mostrecent ON info.donorid = mostrecent.donorid
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(donationdate, '%Y-%m') <
            CASE gender
                WHEN 'f' THEN 
                    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
                ELSE
                    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
                END
        ORDER BY gender, donationdate";  // ordered just for fun
```

When I ran your `female` query on my demo schema, it returned an error.  I assume your code was producing the same error -- hence the query's return value was not an iterable result set; there was a syntax error.

> ```
> SELECT donorid,fname,mname,gender,dob,zone,city,phoneno,bloodtype 
> FROM donor_info 
> where donorid=(
>   SELECT donorid
>   FROM donor_record
>   group by donorid
>   Having (DATE_FORMAT(MAX(donationdate), '%m') < 4 or DATE_FORMAT(MAX(donationdate), '%Y')< ".date('Y').")
>       and gender='f')
> ```
>
> Query Error: Error: ER_SUBQUERY_NO_1_ROW: Subquery returns more than 1
>   row

Now, if there are no error with my suggested query and your `$this->conn->query()` does provide a result set as an array of associative arrays, then this should work as desired:

```
$genderLookup = ['f' => 'female', 'm' => 'male'];
foreach ($this->conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    $result[$genderLookup[$row['gender']]][] = $row;
}
if (!isset($result['female'])) {
    $result['female'] = false;
}
if (!isset($result['male'])) {
    $result['male'] = false;
}
return $result;
```

I have optimized your code so that only one trip to the database is executed.  Fewer trips is better.

p.s. if you, for some reason, cannot directly use `foreach()` on your `query()`'s return value, then you'll need to use iterated [`fetch()` calls](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

p.p.s. I believe you had a typo in your variable naming whereby the initial storage of the result sets was not gender-specific.  (`$info[]`)